# How to use HttpContext to obtain value of int instead of string?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, forms, web-services

I have the current line that requests a product # from a text box:

```
 string[] productNumbers = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues("ProductNumber");
```

I attempted to adapt it to obtain the value from Qty as well:

```
 int[] qty = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues("quantity_input");
```

But I receive an error that it is unable to convert string to int. So how can I use this go obtain an Int? I just want to grab it.

> "CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'int'"

My full code is:

```
CartItemCollection items = new CartItemCollection();
Cart cart = Core.GetCartObject();
string skus = "";
string debugStr = "";
Product product = null;
int[] qty = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues("quantity_input");
try
{
    string[] productNumbers = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues("ProductNumber");
    foreach (string productNumber in productNumbers)
    {
        debugStr = debugStr + "-p=" + productNumber;
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productNumber.Trim()) && !productNumber.StartsWith("Enter Product #"))
        {
            try
            {   //redirect if no product found
                product = Core.GetProductObjectByProductNumber(productNumber);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                debugStr = debugStr + "-e=noproductfound";
                continue; //do nothing, process the next user input
            }
            //check if we have a valid product object, allow virtual and other type(s) for adding directly to cart which may need special handling
            if(product != null)
            {
                debugStr = debugStr + "-t=" + product.ProductTypeName;
                if(!product.ProductTypeName.Equals("NORMAL"))
                {
                    //assume VIRTUAL (or other type) and redirect for selecting child/group products or other special handling
                    form.Redirect("product.aspx?p=" + product.ProductNumber);
                }
                else
                {
                    debugStr = debugStr + "-a=noattributesadd";
                    CartItem item = new CartItem(context);
                    item.ProductId = product.ProductId;
                    item.Quantity = qty;
                    items.Add(item);
                }
                skus = skus + ";" + productNumber;
                product = null;  //reset the product object in case the next product number submitted is invalid
            }  //product not null
        }  //sanity check for empty or default data
    }  //iterate on each product submitted
    cart.AddItems(items);
    form.Redirect("cart.aspx?skus=" + skus);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    form.AddError("*** ProductNumber provided was not found ***");
    form.Redirect("quickorder.aspx?qo=2&e=" + e.Message);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you add more info to your problem ? C# or Java ? Which line provoke the error. etc. You add a sample of the data too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are going to have to convert the string values to integers, E.g.

```
List<int> qty = new List<int>();
foreach (string item in HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues("quantity_input"))
{
    qty.Add(int.Parse(item));
}
```

Use `TryParse` if you want to guard against non-numeric values.

Comment: I received the error:

 CS0246: The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Var is an implicit type (kind of alias of type). Here you can replace it with "string".

Comment: @aloisdg I just tried that, error I received is: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'string'

Comment: Updated to remove `var`, presumably your using < .net 3.5?

Comment: @AlexK. Read into the other answer : He's using .NET 2

Answer (score 0):

It will always return a string[], you can use the following Linq statement to convert the string[] to an int[].

```
string[] result = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues("quantity_input");
int[] quantityInputs = result.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: For the 2nd line, I received the error:

CS1525: Invalid expression term '>'

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5477; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5479

Comment: Are you using the System.Linq assembly?